# Transfer a file from client to server using SUN RPC

Tags: objective-c, c, operating-system, rpc, sunrpc

I am trying to transfer a text file from a client to a server implemented using SunRPC. I was able to transfer the data but only the first four characters. Initially I could only get one character as the data type of the variable that I had defined is character pointer.

add.x file

```
struct file_details {
    unsigned int file_len; 
    int *file_val;
};

struct add_in {
    int *author;
    int *title;
    struct file_details *file;
};

struct node {
    int id;
    int *author;
    int *title;
    struct file_details *f;
    struct node *next;
};

struct info_out {
    int *author;
    int *title;
};

typedef struct node* add_out;
typedef struct node* list_out;
typedef struct node* list_in;
typedef int info_in;
typedef int fetch_in;
typedef char* fetch_out;
```

This is the client code

```
int * read_file(char* path){
    FILE *file;
    int *buffer;
    long file_length;

    file = fopen(path, "rb");
    if(file == NULL){
        perror("Unable to open file");
        exit(1);
    }

    file_length = f_length(path);
    printf("%ld", file_length);
    buffer=(int *)malloc(file_length*4);
    if(buffer == NULL){
       perror("Memory Allocation failed");
       exit(1);
    }

    fread(buffer, file_length, 1, file);
    fclose(file);

    return buffer;
}

int f_length(char* path) {
    FILE *fp;
    long file_len; 
    fp = fopen(path, "rb");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    file_len = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    return file_len;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    CLIENT *cl;
    add_in in;
    add_out *out;
    list_out *l;
    list_out *temp;

    if(argc > 2) {
        cl = clnt_create(argv[1], FILE_TRANSFER, FILE_VERS, "udp");
        in.author = (int *)malloc(strlen(argv[3])*4);
        in.title = (int *)malloc(strlen(argv[4])*4);
        in.author = argv[3];
        in.title = argv[4];
        in.file = (struct file_details *)malloc(sizeof(struct file_details));
        in.file->file_val = (int *)malloc(f_length(argv[5])*4);
        in.file->file_val = read_file(argv[5]); 
        in.file->file_len = f_length(argv[5]);
        if (strcmp(argv[2],"add") == 0){
            out = add_proc_1(&in, cl);
            if(out == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s\n", clnt_sperror(cl,argv[1]));
            }
            else {
                printf("%s added", (*out)->title);
            }
        }

    }

    exit(0);

}
```

My Server code:

```
add_out * 
add_proc_1_svc(add_in *in, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    int file_length = in->file->file_len;
    static add_out  result;    
    char *a = (char *)malloc(file_length*4);
    char *b = (char *)malloc(file_length*4);
    a = in->author;
    node *temp, *newfile; 
    static node *start = NULL;
    newfile = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newfile->f = (file_details *)malloc(sizeof(file_details));
    newfile->author = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    newfile->title = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    newfile->author = in->author;
    newfile->title = in->title;
    newfile->f->file_val = in->file->file_val;
    b = in->file->file_val;
    newfile->f->file_len = file_length;
    newfile->id = rand();
    newfile->next = NULL;    
    if(start == NULL){
       start = newfile;
    }
    else {
        for(temp = start; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next);
        temp->next = newfile;
    }
    result = newfile;
    return &result;
}
```

why is it that when I define int * I am getting 4 character in the server side and 1 when I use char *. Is it the problem with the datatype which I have define. Can anyone suggest me an alternative approach?

Answer (score 1):

I could manage to solve it,

We can use the string datatype which is there in SunRPC, So modified my add.x code,

```
struct file_details {
    unsigned int file_len; 
    string file_val<>;
};

struct add_in {
    string author<>;
    string title<>;
    struct file_details *file;
};

struct node {
    int id;
    string author<>;
    string title<>;
    struct file_details *f;
    struct node *next;
};

struct info_out {
    string author<>;
    string title<>;
};

typedef struct node* add_out;
typedef struct node* list_out;
typedef struct node* list_in;
typedef int info_in;
typedef int fetch_in;
typedef char* fetch_out;
```